# Time n-dimensional series clustering matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a set of time-sequences, every sequence is made of several frames, every frame is represented by an n-dimensional array of features.

I'd like to do DTW and K-means clustering on the set, I tried looking up for resources on the web with very little success. Do you have suggestions on how I could approach the problem or if there are already implemented algorithms available?

Comment: matlab has kmeans clustering in the statistics toolbox. Documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html). You need to format your data into columns representing features or variables and rows representing samples. It looks like DTW is not implemented in matlab toolboxes but is available on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43156-dynamic-time-warping--dtw-)

Comment: k-means minimizes variances. Using it with other distance metrics may stop it from converging in the worst case.

Comment: While I understand how to apply kmeans to normal feature vectors representing the different frames, time-sequences have one more dimension, representing time, which is how the feature vectors changes along it. And that's my issue, since I have no idea how to make it work.